# Facebook connect, get the email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a strange behavior on facebook connect using `/me?email`

1. I created 2 accounts on facebook
2. I added differents emails for both account
3. I put the email to be in public profile for both.

When I connected with the first account I get the email when I try with `/me`, with the second not. What can be the problem ? Please help me and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Afaik emails need to be verified by Facebook. Also, you need to make sure that each accounts authorized the App with the `email` permission.